# bold tikz text decoration

Tags: tikz-pgf, typography, tikz-decorations

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0, 0) -- (2, 2);
  \path [
   postaction={decorate},
     decoration={
       text along path,
       raise=0.2cm,
       text={Text 2}
%       text={\bf Text 2}                                                                                                                                                                                   
  }
] (0, 0) -- (2, 2);
\node at (0, 2) {\bf Text 1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Compilation stops if I substitute

```
   text={Text 2}
```

with

```
   text={\bf Text 2}
```

How to have bold text decorations with tikz?

Comment: Does `font=\bfseries` work? Note that `\bf` is deprecated in LaTeX and shouldn't be used anymore.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik `font=\bfseries` doesn't work

Comment: Maybe `text={|\bf|Text 2}`

Comment: @MarkWibrow `|\bf|` works. Is it the correct form to use?